# Benefits of blocks/inheritance/extends over includes

Tags: python, django

So I'm building an application using django. A few people in my team think I should be using includes in my templates rather than following the blocks/extends paradigm. They argue that:

- Inheritance is too much logic for future maintainers
- Includes are much easier to follow
- We shouldn't limit future maintenance to "django programmers"

I'd really rather not butcher my application's templates, so I'm trying to come up with some convincing reasons (for non-django users) as to why inheritance really is the way forward. I'd love to hear some more views on this.

A few reasons I've come up with already:

- Much more DRY. Ensures that boilerplate html structures only need to be defined in one place; much less risk of templates getting out of sync
- Keeps content which belongs in templates, in templates, and out of views; for example:

  `<title>{% block title %}My Website{% endblock %}</title>`

  vs

  `<title>{{ pagetitle }}</title>`

  This gives the front-end maintainer much more control over the front-end, without having to delve into back-end views
- Front end coders already have to be familiar with the concept of inheritance of extending from a base / overriding defaults; consider the following css:

  ```
  .nav {
    color: blue;
  }

  .nav.active {
    color: purple;
  }
  ```

Any good reasoning you can throw into the mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inheritance makes it easier (at least IMHO) to create a master base.html template and let all of the other pages `extends` it. This leaves all layout/styling to be specified in that one file, and the rest simply use tags with `id` and `class` in a standardized way.

It is good to remember that the argument to `extends` (as well as `include`) can be a *variable*. Our `templates/base.html` is one line:

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

where `base_template` is set in our master context processor. This, together with a simple  admin widget that changes `session.base_template`, has allowed our designer to create multiple layouts and switch between them with a single click. She absolutely loves it.